# invoking an XML schema in a document

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created an XML schema and uploaded it. It a validates. When I tried to use it to create a document, it isn't recognized. I have tried various combinations of schema attributes. The goal is not to use namespace prefixes on tags in the document. Here's the start of a test document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<indexdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd">
  <source creator="Txt2Arc" version="3.0" time="2017-01-20T14:41:49"/>
  <fonts>
    <font id="0">
     <fname>Arial</fname>
     <aname>Arial</aname>
    </font>
  </fonts>
  ...
</indexdata>   <!-- added by edit to complete the XML -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`xsi:schemaLocation` has two parts, a namespace URI and an URL that is used to retrieve the XML schema document. In your case, both are exactly the same string, so the following works:

**Referencing a remote schema document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<indexdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd">
    <source creator="Txt2Arc" version="3.0" time="2017-01-20T14:41:49"/>
    <fonts>
        <font id="0">
            <fname>Arial</fname>
            <aname>Arial</aname>
        </font>
    </fonts>
</indexdata>
```

But the test document is not valid with respect to the schema at http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd because some elements should not be in the `http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd` namespace (`source` and `fonts`) and an element is missing (`records`).

---

A naive way to correct your test document would be to introduce `xmlns=""` in several places to avoid elements ending up in the default namespace. But a better solution is to turn the default namespace declaration:

```
xmlns="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd"
```

into a declaration with a *prefix*:

```
xmlns:ixml="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd"
```

and only use it on the one element that should be in this namespace, `indexdata`. Then, the document becomes

**A valid instance of this schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ixml:indexdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd"
 xmlns:ixml="http://www.LevTechInc.com/Schemas/IXML.xsd">
    <source creator="Txt2Arc" version="3.0" time="2017-01-20T14:41:49"/>
    <fonts>
        <font id="0">
            <fname>Arial</fname>
            <aname>Arial</aname>
        </font>
    </fonts>
    <records></records>
</ixml:indexdata>
```

Comment: @DaveReam Glad to hear that. If my post has answered your question, please consider accepting it. Thanks! More help on accepting an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.